# Searching Bluetooth Nearby in 6.0.1

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'am working with an App that search nearby bluetooth. I use the following codes, it works find in 5.0 it returns bluetooth devices nearby but when I Test in 6.0.1 `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` is not called, Only `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` and `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` are called.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
}
private final BroadcastReceiver bReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        System.out.println(action);
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            System.out.println(device);
        }
    }
};
public void onSearch(View v){
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    System.out.println(bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery());
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(bReciever, intentFilter);

}
```

My Question Is why Did the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND was not called in 6.0.1? Thank you.

Comment: Did you find the cause. I have the same issue

Answer (score -1):

did you check the permission in Application Manager?

Goto "**Settings**" -> "**Apps**" -> "**Your App"** -> "**Permissions**".

and check if bluetooth permission are given.

Comment: There's No Request Permission in My Apps Setting Permission. In My manifest I add the Following uses-permission
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>